# android maps circle overlay, dynamically change radius?

Tags: android, maps

I have a MapView in my app and am drawing a few circle overlays on this map. Everything is working fine, but when I zoom on the map, the overlay radius does not change. I have tried searching forums and google for a solution but could not find one that worked for me. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my code:

HelloGoogleMaps.java (main activity)

```
package com.adam.maps;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.OnZoomListener;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity {  
//create new LocationManager
//and LocationListener objects
LocationManager lm;
LocationListener locationListener;

OnZoomListener listener;

//create a new MapView
//and MapController object
MapView mapView;
MapController mc;

RelativeLayout parent;

int num = 4;
//LoopRegion region[] = new LoopRegion[num];
//LoopRegion border[] = new LoopRegion[num];
float regionX[] = {(float) 42.91556645193364, (float) 42.9151598328247, 
        (float) 43.00110298764482, (float) 43.00054196511636};
float regionY[] = {(float) -78.87073255078127, (float) -78.8714594294243, 
        (float) -78.78354466454317, (float) -78.78226256863405};
int regionR[] = {100, 70, 150, 75};
GeoPoint regionC[] = new GeoPoint[num];
CustomOverlay overlay[] = new CustomOverlay[num];
CustomOverlay overlayLoc;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
            "Welcome to 'sound clusters'" , 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //---use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations---
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
        0, 
        0, 
        locationListener);

    //set our mapViewer object to our "mapview" namespace in the xml layout file
    //this allows us to set the zoom control "ON" in our view
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    //this will enable zoom controls, and put it on the screen
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //--------------------------------------------------------//
    parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);

    //-------this is part of creating an overlay icon-------------------------------
    /*List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay =
        new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);*/
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Create new Overlay
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        regionC[i] = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (regionX[i] * 1E6), 
                (int) (regionY[i] * 1E6));
        int newRadius = (int) feetToPixels(mapView.getZoomLevel(), regionR[i]);
        overlay[i] = new CustomOverlay(regionC[i], newRadius);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay[i]);
    }

    //-------this is part of creating an overlay icon-------------------------------
    /*OverlayItem overlayitem =
         new OverlayItem(point, "Hello", "I'm in Athens, Greece!");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);*/
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setZoom(20);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
            "Zoom level: " + mapView.getZoomLevel(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

//not sure what this does, but Google says you need it----//
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------//    

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{

    //@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc != null) {

            List overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            // first remove old overlay
            if (overlays.size() > 0) {
                for (Iterator iterator = overlays.iterator(); iterator
                        .hasNext();) {
                    iterator.next();
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }

            GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            overlayLoc = new CustomOverlay(p, 5);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(overlayLoc);
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
                mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay[i]);
            }
            //mc.animateTo(p);
            //mc.setZoom(16);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    //@Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    //@Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
        Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

//custom functions--------------------------------------------------------------------
private static final double equatorFeet = 131479920; 
private double feetToPixels(int zoomLevel, int feet) { 
    double equatorPixels = 256; 
    for (int i = 1; i < zoomLevel; i++) { 
        equatorPixels = equatorPixels * 2; 
    } 
    double pixelPerFoot = equatorPixels / equatorFeet; 
    return feet * pixelPerFoot; 
} 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

And the Overlay class CustomOverlay.java

```
package com.adam.maps;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;

public class CustomOverlay extends Overlay {

private GeoPoint geopoint;
private int rad;

public CustomOverlay(GeoPoint point, int radius) {
    geopoint = point;
    rad = radius;
}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    // Transform geo-position to Point on canvas
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    Point point = new Point();
    //store the transformed geopoint into a point with pixel values
    projection.toPixels(geopoint, point);

    /*// text "My Location"
    Paint text = new Paint();
    text.setAntiAlias(true);
    text.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    text.setTextSize(12);
    text.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);*/

    // the circle to mark the spot
    Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    //fill region
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    circlePaint.setAlpha(90);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, rad, circlePaint);
    //border region
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    circlePaint.setAlpha(255);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, rad, circlePaint);

    /*canvas.drawText("My Location", point.x + 3 * CIRCLERADIUS, point.y + 3
            * CIRCLERADIUS, text);*/
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this thread is a few months old, but there are ALWAYS easier ways to achieve very similar results.
I understand that the presented method gives a much more precise calculation regarding the size of the circle, but still, if you only need any circle around averaging some area, this code requires much less processing making the UI more fluid:

```
public class MapCircleOverlay extends Overlay {

private GeoPoint point;
private Paint paint1, paint2;

public MapCircleOverlay(GeoPoint point) {
    this.point = point;

    paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setARGB(128, 0, 0, 255);
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint1.setDither(false);
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    paint2 = new Paint();
    paint2.setARGB(64, 0, 0, 255);  

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

    Point pt = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, null);
    float radius = (float) Math.pow(2, mapView.getZoomLevel() - 10);

    if(radius < canvas.getHeight()/25){
        radius = canvas.getHeight()/25;
    }

    canvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, radius, paint2);
    canvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, radius, paint1);

}

}
```

Explanation:
the documentation states that for each zoomLevel the map doubles (or halves) the size, so as long as the radius is doubling or halving, its size will be consistent across drawings.

The "-10" can be changed to vary the size of the circle (maybe be done in Constructor if desired)

Also the min_r (minimum radius) calculation can be tweaked as desired, it's only there to prevent the circle to completely disappear as the user zooms out.

hope it helps someone  ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class MapCircleOverlay extends Overlay {

private GeoPoint point;
private Paint paint1, paint2;
private float radius; //in meters

public MapCircleOverlay(GeoPoint point, float radius) {
    this.point = point;

    paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setARGB(128, 0, 0, 255);
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint1.setDither(false);
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    paint2 = new Paint();
    paint2.setARGB(64, 0, 0, 255);

    this.radius = radius;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

    Point pt = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, null);
    float projectedRadius = mapView.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(radius);

    canvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, projectedRadius, paint2);
    canvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, projectedRadius, paint1);

}

}
```

I modified Bundius's answer so it works with meters that you can input as part of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
class myLocationOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

    private static final double defaultLatitude = Double.parseDouble("your_default_latitude");
    private static final double defaultLongitude = Double.parseDouble("your_default_longitude");
    private static final float defaultAccuracy = 250f; // or whatever you wish it to be


    Location currentLocation; // this should be already known

    private Paint accuracyPaint;
    private Point center;
    private Point left;
    private Drawable drawable;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        accuracyPaint = new Paint();
        accuracyPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        accuracyPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);

        drawable = mapView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_location_dot);
        width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        center = new Point();
        left = new Point();
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        float accuracy;
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

        if(currentLocation == null) {
            latitude = defaultLatitude;
            longitude = defaultLongitude;
            accuracy = defaultAccuracy;
        } else {
            latitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            accuracy = currentLocation.getAccuracy();
        }            

        float[] result = new float[1];

        Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, latitude, longitude + 1, result);
        float longitudeLineDistance = result[0];

        GeoPoint leftGeo = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1E6), (int)((longitude - accuracy / longitudeLineDistance) * 1E6));
        projection.toPixels(leftGeo, left);
        projection.toPixels(myLocationPoint, center);
        int radius = center.x - left.x;

        accuracyPaint.setColor(0xff6666ff);
        accuracyPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, accuracyPaint);

        accuracyPaint.setColor(0x186666ff);
        accuracyPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, accuracyPaint);

        drawable.setBounds(center.x - width / 2, center.y - height / 2, center.x + width / 2, center.y + height / 2);
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Change the R.drawable.**my_location_dot** with whatever you use as location marker and see that the currentLocation is known

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i know the acepted answer is old but exist a native and better solution.

```
 // Add a circle in Sydney
 Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689))
     .radius(10000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

I hope this help someone =)

Reference : [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CircleOptions.html)

Comment: How would you change the radius after it has been added to the screen?

Answer (score 1):

```
private CircleOptions circle;
double radiusInMeters = 50.0;
int strokeColor = 0xffff0000; //red outline
int shadeColor = 0x44ff0000;

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

 ...
    LatLng mylatlng= new LatLng(currentLat, currentLon);
    circle = new CircleOptions().center(mylatlng).radius(radiusInMeters).fillColor(shadeColor).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(3);
    mMap.addCircle(circle);

 ...

}
```