# Android : radius circle on my location point

Tags: android

Good morning, what is the radius blue circle that appears on my location and how I can draw it in my android application.

[image: like this]

Thanks

Comment: the circle is the accuracy of the gps location. you can use **com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay** which is part of the google's map api

Comment: And This MyLocationOverlay draw the circle and also the little ball into the circle ??

Comment: check this [LINK](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=148). the image does not show the ring. but you will get one if the accuracy is low.

Comment: ok but then what is the method to draw the ring ?

Comment: it automatically draws the ring. if you want yours you can simply extent it and override the ondraw

Comment: Check [this answer][1]. I think, this is exactly what you need.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722490/android-maps-circle-overlay-dynamically-change-radius