# Java Android: Google Maps Scale radius of circle (CircleOptions)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my app I display a large number of circles alongside a track, the problem is that the radius is fixed.

```
  circleOpt.radius(10).strokeColor(circleColor).fillColor(trackColor);
```

Is there an equivalent of [circleMarker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker) for google maps android? So the circle automatically resizes based on the zoom level of the map.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737054/how-can-i-draw-a-static-target-circle-on-google-maps/35751087#35751087

Comment: @antonio, thanks. I think this is unsuited since my app must support large datasets (of circles if you will).